# Why are there factors of $2 \pi r$ in this volume integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, dimensional-analysis

I have a question regarding the solution to part of this homework question:

[image: cylinder 1]

> An infinite filled cylinder of radius $a$ contains a 3D charge density $\rho$. A thin-walled hollow cylinder of radius $b \gt a$ centered on the same axis surrounds it, and contains a charge with the same charge per unit length, but with opposite sign.
>
> a) Compute the electric field $\vec E$ everywhere.
>
> b) Compute the electrostatic potential $V$, defined by $\vec E = −\nabla V$, everywhere, subject to
>   $V(r \to \infty) = 0$
>
> c) Compute the energy in the electric field, per unit length. The 3D energy density is $U_E = \varepsilon_0 E^2/2$.

---

I only have a question regarding the solution to part c). But, unfortunately for my question to make sense I will have to typeset the full solutions to a), b) and c):

[image: cylinder 2]

The arrangement is shown above and the solution to part a) is

> By symmetry, the electric field is radial everywhere. For $r \lt a$, Gauss’s theorem in a cylinder of unit length (or use a length $L$ if preferred) gives $$\oint \vec E \cdot d\vec S =\frac{Q}{\varepsilon_0}\implies E 2 \pi r=\frac{\pi r^2 \rho}{\varepsilon_0}\implies E=\frac{\rho r}{2 \varepsilon_0}$$
>   For $a \lt r \lt b$ the charge enclosed is $\pi a^2 \rho$, so $$E 2 \pi r=\frac{\pi a^2 \rho}{2 \varepsilon_0}\implies E=\frac{\rho a^2}{2 r \varepsilon_0}$$
>   For $r \gt b$ the charge enclosed is zero, so $$E=0$$

The image below is just for clarity and it shows the cylinder as viewed from its cross-section:

[image: cylinder 3]

---

The solution to part b) is

> In cylindrical polars, the radial gradient is $\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$, so $$V(r)=-\int_{\infty}^r E(r^{\prime})\,dr^{\prime}$$
>   Evidently $V=0$ for $r \gt b$.
>
> For $a \lt r \lt b$,
>   $$V(r)=-\int_{b}^r \frac{\rho a^2}{2 r^{\prime} \varepsilon_0} \, dr^{\prime}=-\frac{\rho a^2}{2 \varepsilon_0}\ln\left(\frac{r}{b}\right)$$
>
> For $r \lt a$,
>   $$V(r)=-\int_a^r \frac{\rho r^{\prime}}{2 \varepsilon_0} \,dr^{\prime}-\frac{\rho a^2}{2 \varepsilon_0} \ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = \frac{\rho\left(a^2-r^2 \right)}{4 \varepsilon_0}-\frac{\rho a^2}{2 \varepsilon_0} \ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$$

---

The solution to part c) is

> The energy per unit length is
>   $$\frac{\varepsilon_0}{2} \int_0^b E^2(r) \, dr = \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2} \left(\frac{\rho}{2 \varepsilon_0}\right)^2 \left[\int_0^a {r^{\prime}}^2 \color{red}{2 \pi r^{\prime}} \, dr^{\prime}+\int_a^b \frac{1}{{r^{\prime}}^2} \color{red}{2 \pi r^{\prime}} \, dr^{\prime}\right]$$ $$=\frac{\pi \rho^2 a^4}{16 \varepsilon_0} \left[1+4 \ln\left(\frac{b}{a} \right) \right]$$

---

Now, finally, my question is very simple. Why are those factors of $2 \pi r^{\prime}$ (shown in red) present in the integrands?

Since the question asked for the energy per unit **length** I think that the integral should be given by $$\frac{\varepsilon_0}{2}\int_0^b E^2(r) \, dr = \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2} \left(\frac{\rho}{2 \varepsilon_0}\right)^2 \left[\int_0^a {r^{\prime}}^2 \, dr^{\prime}+\int_a^b \frac{1}{{r^{\prime}}^2} \, dr^{\prime} \right]$$

I note that the formula for $U_E$ is energy per unit *volume*, but the $2 \pi r^{\prime} \, dr^{\prime}$ implies that the integration is performed over infinitesimal annuli from the inner radius ($r=0$) to the outer radius ($r=b$). If this is the case then dimensionally this is a surface integral (and not a volume integral).

Could someone please explain what necessitates the $2 \pi r^{\prime} \, dr^{\prime}$ factors in the integrands?

---

Images shown in this question were taken from [this pdf by MIT](http://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/802TEAL3D/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide05.pdf)

Comment: Considering the amount of physical interpretations here, this probably fits better in Physics SE

Comment: @Lucas and they will just send it back here. Their reasoning will be, 'this question is solely about mathematics', but I can try if you like....

Comment: Energy density is $E^2 \epsilon_0/2$.  You have to integrate over all space, not just with respect to $r$, so your definition of energy with just an integral with respect to $r$ is incorrect.  The $2 \pi r$ comes about to handle the angular direction.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for your reply, I still don't really understand why we need $2 \pi r$. Can you please elaborate on this in an answer perhaps? But the question does ask for energy per unit length so I am really confused as to why it must be over all space

Comment: Basically the volume includes the factor of $L$. $dV=2\pi r dr L$

Comment: It's the energy _in the cylinder_ per unit length _of the cylinder._ One way to think of it is if you cut the cylinder with a plane perpendicular to the axis, and then again with another plane one unit from the first plane, how much energy is in the volume between the planes? The distance between the planes is the "length" that you are supposed to look at "per unit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy of the electric field in a volume $V$ is given by

$$\mathcal{E} = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_{V} E^2 dV$$

Let $V$ be a cylinder along the rod from $0$ to $\ell$ of infinite radius. So here you have

\begin{align}
\mathcal{E} &= \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_{V} E^2 dV 
\\
&=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_{0}^\ell\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty E^2(r)rdrd\theta dz
\\
&=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_{0}^\ell\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^b E^2(r)rdrd\theta dz
\\
&=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_0^bE^2(r) [2\pi r \ell] dr
\end{align}
Since $E = 0$ for $r>b$. Therefore the energy per length $\ell$ is
$$\mathcal{E}/\ell = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_0^bE^2(r) [2\pi r] dr$$
by symmetry this holds for any cylinder with the same orientation.

Comment: Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the electromagnetic details for a moment. Let $u$ denote an energy per unit volume. Across a cylinder of finite length, the stored energy is a volume integral of $u$. The energy per unit length is some quantity that integrates across the cylinder's length to give that stored energy. It is therefore a double integral of $u$, across the cylinder's cross section. Since $u$ depends only on $r^\prime\in[0,\,r]$, not on the angle $\theta$ or a distance $z$ along the cylinder's axis, this double integral's operator is$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^rdr^\prime r^\prime=\int_0^r2\pi r^\prime dr^\prime.$$In particular, the energy per unit length is$$\int_0^r2\pi r^\prime u(r^\prime)dr^\prime.$$ The quoted calculation splits the integral up to $b$, the maximum $r$ for which $u\ne0$, into the $[0,\,a]$ and $[a,\,b]$ pieces, although it has an unfortunate typo in that the latter uses $\frac{1}{r^{\prime2}}$ instead of $\frac{a^4}{r^{\prime2}}$, an error exposed by dimensional analysis.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, so the correct expression for the energy per unit length is $\dfrac{\pi \rho^2}{16 \varepsilon_0} \left[ a^4+4 \ln\left(\dfrac{b}{a} \right) \right]$. Do you agree with this?

Comment: @user395550 No, the $a^4$ should still be outside.

Comment: Thanks, so the final answer of $\dfrac{\pi \rho^2 a^4}{16 \varepsilon_0} \left[1+4 \ln\left(\dfrac{b}{a} \right) \right]$ is still correct?

Comment: @user395550 Yes. When my answer mentioned a missing $a^4$ factor, it was in the integral on $[a,\,b]$. It's merely an author's typo.